# Get install date of cartridge through SNMP

Tags: java, printing, snmp

I'm currently working on a Java application that involves getting information from a printer through SNMP.

I'm almost there, but I need the OID to get the install date of the cartridges (I already got the toner values and etc.)

Any word on the OID that's needed to retrieve this date would be great.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you want to have a chance to get an answer to this question you might want to be a bit more specific. What model are we talking about? What external resource/mib/manual have you used so far (to get the toner values)? What do these resources mention about the value you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

There is Printer MIB, which is supposed to be the standard.

http://www.oidview.com/mibs/0/Printer-MIB.html

But from my experience, it will vary a lot from each vendor, with some respecting the standar, other don't, an even variations in different models from same vendor. If as i suspect there is no luck with printer mib, you'll have to walk the whole table and compare the values returned with known values to reverse engineer the oids.